# How to convert box shadow values from RGB value to HEX values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to convert `box-shadow:rgb(255, 255, 255) 10px 10px 0px , rgb(0, 0, 0) 10px 10px 0px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 10px 10px 0px` to `box-shadow:#FFF 10px 10px 0px , #000 10px 10px 0px, #FFF 10px 10px 0px`

Can any one help me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a script that does this, or do it manually and just don't know how?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is any API / script for converting the box-shadow from RGB to HEX

Comment: possible duplicate of [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Comment: Actually I am getting a long string with multiple drop shadow values. Instead of using regEx and filtering out the multiple rgb values from the entire string, wanted to know if there is any already existing javascript code snippet or any DOM API's...

Answer (score 0):

to convert RGB to hex you need to find the different source for each r, g, and b  find the hex for each and every source based on the length

```
function findMyHex(get) {
    var hex = get.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function tohex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + findMyHex(r) + findMyHex(g) + findMyHex(b);
}

console.log(tohex(255, 255, 255));
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use `.toString(base)` to convert a number into another base (in this case it's base 16 -> *hexadecimal*).

An example:

```
var r = 255;
var g = 128;
var b = 219;
var hex = "#" + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16);
// hex = #ff80db
```

You just need to run something like this through your desired text in a loop and replace every occurence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe overkill,

```
function rgbToHex(str_rgb, withShorts, b) {
    var r, g, h;
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        withShorts = !!withShorts;
        h = str_rgb.match(/rgba?\( *(\d+) *, *(\d+) *, *(\d+)/);
        r = +h[1];
        g = +h[2];
        b = +h[3];
    } else {
        r = str_rgb | 0, g = withShorts | 0, b = b | 0;
        withShorts = !!arguments[3];
    }
    r = r.toString(16), g = g.toString(16), b = b.toString(16);
    r = ('0' + r).slice(-2), g = ('0' + g).slice(-2), b = ('0' + b).slice(-2);
    if (withShorts) {
        if (r[0] === r[1])
            if(g[0] === g[1])
                if (b[0] === b[1])
                    return '#' + (r[0] + g[0] + b[0]).toUpperCase();
    }
    return '#' + (r + g + b).toUpperCase();
}
```

Now have

```
// ints
rgbToHex(255, 255, 255);       // "#FFFFFF"
rgbToHex(255, 255, 255, true); // "#FFF"
// strings
rgbToHex('rgb(255, 255, 255)');       // "#FFFFFF"
rgbToHex('rgb(255, 255, 255)', true); // "#FFF"
// ignores alpha
rgbToHex('rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'); // "#FFFFFF"
// does padding
rgbToHex(1, 10, 14); // "#010A0E"
```